# The nuances of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have been using objective c for a few months now, using different foundation classes and generally playing around with the language.

In my own experience nothing has been more confusing than UITableView; Below is a bit of code that does not do much.

```
//the header file 
@interface SLDataBankListTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

//implementation
@interface SLDataBankListTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SLDataSourceObject* dataSource;

@end

@implementation SLDataBankListTableViewController

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    _dataSource = [[SLDataSourceObject alloc] init];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _dataSource.dataBankNames.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"reuse"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_dataSource.dataBankNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

I have successfully used this class for over a dozen times and every time I make some stupid mistake like now. Finally  I gathered some courage and decided to ask for help.

What are the subtle things, nuances of this class that I don't seem to grasp?

Edit: this is a part of a small program, other parts of it work fine, but the table displays nothing; Some changes have been recommended that are important but did not solve the problem.

Comment: If you are new to Foundation and UIKit then a simple tutorial will solve all your problems (if you don't understand Apple's documentation). Most tutorials are now based around Swift but there are some older Objective-C tutorials (a lot on iTunesU). For a modern iTunesU Swift tutorial, I recommend Stanford's 'Developing iOS 9 Apps in Swift`. The most recent Objective-C tutorial I could find on iTunesU was 'Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little hard to debug without known what is not working, but I see some things which might help you out.

1. `UITableViewController` has its own tableview but you seem to have another tableview wired up in a nib.  Either use the `UITableViewController` tableview, or create your own, don't do both.
2. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are creating a new cell every time instead of reusing the cells you have.
3. The delegate methods for the tableview can be called before `viewWillAppear`. You should create your datasource object earlier.  I suggest `viewDidLoad:`. (Another reason `viewWillAppear` is a bad choice is that it can be call multiple times, and you can end up creating and destroying many datasource objects for no reason)
   Hope that helps.

Comment: This was very helpful, does the 2nd advice stand even if I know for sure that I'm gonna have 6 cells ?

Comment: If you create a cell every time it will work. But you are doing it wrong. Scrolling will be slow and you are losing most of the power of a tableview. It is not a big deal if there are only 6 cells, but I believe in doing thing right.

Answer (score 1):

The big thing to remember about a table view is that it's a way for user to interact with an array of objects.  The array is represented by a datasource, and the datasource methods describe what the view needs to know:

1. how many objects are in the array (called `numberOfRowsInSection:`)
2. how to display each one of the objects (called `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)

To answer the latter question, the datasource must answer a view.  That view's job -- like any view -- is to represent an object for the user.  In row the table view uses a `UITableViewCell`.

The datasource array can be arbitrarily large, so *directly* mapping UITableViewCells to its elements can get arbitrarily expensive in memory terms.  Rather than create a cell for every object in the array, the table view *reuses* cells.

When a cell scrolls off the top, the "new" one that appears at the bottom isn't new, it's the old cell handed back to the datasource to be reconfigured for the new row.  To accomplish this, your datasource is expected to not allocate a new cell, as @JonRose correctly points out, but to ask the table view for a reused cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.